# A delete button for each field

Tags: php

I have a table of items from my database and for each item I want a delete button.

Currently it IS working, but the button shows the ID number, and I want it to just say "delete".

I still want it to delete based on the joke.ID

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT joke.id, joketext, jokedate, name, email FROM joke INNER JOIN author ON authorid = author.id");

echo "<form action='delete1.php' method='post'>
<table border='1'>
   <tr>
      <th>Joke</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>";

   while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['joketext'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['jokedate'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='submit' name='deleteItem' value='".$row['id']."' /></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
   echo "</form></br>";

   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

this is the `delete1.php`

```
    if ( isset( $_POST['deleteItem'] ) and is_numeric( $_POST['deleteItem'] ) ) {
        // here comes your delete query: use $_POST['deleteItem'] as your id
        mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM joke WHERE id='$_POST[deleteItem]'");
    }
    mysqli_close( $con );
    header('Location: joke1.php');
    exit();
?>
```

I would just like the button to say "delete"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go other way round. Make a hidden input element as follows:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='deleteItem' value='".$row['id']."'>";
```

And change the existing one to

```
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='Delete' /></td>";
```

That's it.

EDIT1: You'll have to keep a different form for each Joke.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['joketext'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['jokedate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<form action='delete1.php' method='post'>
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='deleteItem' value='".$row['id']."'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete' />";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: The HTML in your *EDIT1* is truly terrible. Just put the form, hidden input and submit button all in the last table cell

Comment: You just missed a little syntax in EDIT1 other than that works great, thanks

Comment: Yeah. May be. Actually I just copy-pasted lines from your code, and never compiled it or anything. Anyways, glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple way

```
echo "<td><input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='javascript:location.href=\'delete1.php?id=" .$row['id']. "\'' /></td>";
```

**delete1.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) and is_numeric($_GET['id']))
```